# A-Frame reload gif on page refresh

Tags: html, node.js

I want to play a gif for a project I am working on. The gif loads if I save the .HTML file, but when I reload the page the gif unloads and shows a white material on the object

```
<a-entity position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" geometry="primitive:plane" material="shader:gif;src:url(https://media4.giphy.com/media/3j7LjV0ZLiR9bV0DoK/giphy.gif);" gif=""></a-entity>
```

I am using:

```
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-shader/master/dist/aframe-gif-shader.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-shader/master/dist/aframe-gif-shader.min.js"></script>
```

Does someone know how to load the gif on page load/reload?